# Select from multiple tables with multiple conditions

Tags: sql

I have a problem. I have three tabels, named AUTHORS, BOOKS_AUTHORS and BOOKS and I'm trying to select from these three tables only the books written by Lev Tolstoi.
This is what I have right now, but it's not working

```
select   "AUTHORS"."LASTNAME" as "LASTNAME",
     "AUTHORS"."FIRSTNAME" as "FIRSTNAME",
     "BOOKS"."NAME" as "NAME",
 from    "BOOKS_AUTHORS",
     "BOOKS",
     "AUTHORS" 
 where   "AUTHORS"."ID"="BOOKS_AUTHORS"."ID_AUTHOR"
 and     "BOOKS_AUTHORS"."ID_BOOK"="BOOKS"."ID"
 and     "AUTHORS"."LASTNAME"="Tolstoi" 
 and     "AUTHORS"."FIRSTNAME"="Lev"
```

I have tables on this site named iacademy3.oracle.com and the error is

> "ORA-00936: missing expression"

Comment: "Not working" is not an error message nor a description of a problem. What result are you getting? What do you expect? Why?

Comment: Why isn't it working? Syntax error? No results? Are you sure that there is a book linked to that author? Are you sure that author exists? Include some sample data.

Comment: Please learn to use the modern, explicit `JOIN` operator instead of the ancient and fragile implicit joins in the WHERE clause

Comment: String constants have to be supplied with single quotes in SQL. `"Tolstoi"` references a _column_ (which you have done, e.g. with `"ID"`). You probably meant to write `'Tolstoi'`

Comment: Remove the comma from `"BOOKS"."NAME" as "NAME",`. Your list ends there.

Comment: Learn to use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using old `JOIN` syntax, use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax to make it more readable and easy to extend to other join if needed.

```
select 
       a.FIRSTNAME, a.LASTNAME, b.Name as BookName
from AUTHORS a 
inner join BOOKS_AUTHORS bk on bk.ID_AUTHOR = a.id
inner join BOOKS b on b.id = bk.ID_BOOK
where a.FIRSTNAME = 'Lev' and a.LASTNAME = 'Tolstoi';
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an extra comma here:  "BOOKS"."NAME" as "NAME",  -  I removed it below

```
select   "AUTHORS"."LASTNAME" as "LASTNAME",
     "AUTHORS"."FIRSTNAME" as "FIRSTNAME",
     "BOOKS"."NAME" as "NAME"
 from    "BOOKS_AUTHORS",
     "BOOKS",
     "AUTHORS" 
 where   "AUTHORS"."ID"="BOOKS_AUTHORS"."ID_AUTHOR"
 and     "BOOKS_AUTHORS"."ID_BOOK"="BOOKS"."ID"
 and     "AUTHORS"."LASTNAME"="Tolstoi" 
 and     "AUTHORS"."FIRSTNAME"="Lev"
```